# Twilio: does the area code affect SMS delivery speed?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We are a mobile app that uses Twilio for phone number verification.

And experiencing a small percentage of our user base getting their SMS very slow (over 2 mins).

Right now we have ~100 Twilio phone numbers which we use in a round robin chain format (so we don't hit any API limits).

Does the area code of the Twilio phone number that sends the SMS affect delivery speed? If so, we can buy a phone number in each area code and sent user's their verification SMS from a Twilio number in the exact same area code.

Here is an example of a delivery that took several minutes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The area code of a Twilio number should not affect the delivery speed at all. If you are concerned about this then I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and send them some of the message SIDs you're worried about. They can track down why there might be delays with the carriers.

Just as a note, you don't need to do the round robin yourself. Take a look at [Twilio's Copilot](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages-copilot). It allows for [geomatching](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages-copilot#geomatch) (on an international basis) and also gives you [sticky sender](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages-copilot#sticky-sender) so that users will always receive messages from the same number.